# How to execute a function in child component when (change) on a select in the parent component happens

Tags: angular

I have child component with a function that I want to call once the (change) event gets triggered on a select in the parent component. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `@ViewChild`

Try this:

**Parent Component**:

HTML:

```
<select (change)="selectDropdownChange()">
    <option >...</option>
</select>

<child-comp #childRef></child-comp>
```

TS:

`@ViewChild('childRef') childRef: ChildComp;`

```
selectDropdownChange() {
    this.childRef.childFunction();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it results in childRef being undefined do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have u imported `ChildComp`?

Comment: Can u share Parent component html and TS... I will look into it. U can mail me at adritasharma@gmail.com

Comment: I changed up a few things and it work even though I get an error. Changes I made `@ViewChild(ChildComp) childRef: ChildComp;`and added ChildComp to providers. Now when I log this.childRef I get the ChildComp with the childs properties but when I try to access them I get an  error yet it still show the properties value from the child

Comment: Why did u add ChildComp to providers? I think it should be added to `declaration` since it is a component. We add services to providers

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't advise the @AdritaSharma solution since it's not reusable. It requires some boilerplate for every implementation.

I use to adopt this solution:

In parent component:

```
// HTML:
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option>...</option>
</select>
<child-component [value]="value"></child-component>

// TS:
value: string;

onChange(value: string) {
  this.value = value;
}
```

In child component:

```
_value: string;
@Input() 
set value(v) {
  this._value = v;
  // execute your update code
}
get value() {
  return this._value;
}
```